# Sorting the grade and name of students inputting in C#

Tags: c#, sorting, bubble-sort

This is my code:

I also want to get a number from the input of the number for a number of names, and at the end of the sort by the number and the name of the number entered in the output.

*I am not permitted to use classes.*

```
    int[] arr1 = new int[10];
    string[] name = new string[10];
    int n, i, j, tmp;


    Console.Write("\n\nSort elements of array in ascending order :\n");
    Console.Write("----------------------------------------------\n");

    Console.Write("Input the size of array : ");
    n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.Write("Input {0} elements in the array :\n", n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter name {0}", i);
        name[i] = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("element - {0} : ", i);
        arr1[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (arr1[j] < arr1[i])
            {
                tmp = arr1[i];
                arr1[i] = arr1[j];
                arr1[j] = tmp;


            }
        }
    }
    Console.Write("\nElements of array in sorted ascending order:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        Console.Write("{0}, {1}  ", arr1[i],name[i]);
    }
    Console.Write("\n\n");
    Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: I want to get the input of the number and the string. Then sort according to the number

Comment: You've stated what you want, but you haven't stated what the problem is. What is your question?

Comment: You will likely find that it is easier to create a class that contains properties for both the number and the name, and then create a collection of class instances.  Then sort the instances by the number.  That way, the name gets pulled along for the ride.  Otherwise, you will have to manipulate both of the arrays you have.  As it is, you are working with the numbers, but the strings are left alone.

Comment: The problem is that the string does not receive input and the input string appears with any number in the sort

Comment: You also create arrays of length 10, but later ask the user for the size of the array.  You should only instantiate your arrays after you find out how long they should be.  As it is, if the user answers with 14, you will blow yourself out of the water on the 11th element.

Comment: it's true . But I want to do this without a class

Comment: If you want to sort the number array from lowest to highest, and also sort the name array so the names stay at the same index as the numbers they were originally paired with (at least that's how I'm interpreting your question), then inside the `if (arr1[j] < arr1[i])` statement block you need to also swap the items in the name array at the same indexes as the item you're swapping in the number array.

Comment: I am not going to provide a full answer to a homework question, but I have just given you the solution. Please give it a try and come back with a new question if you get stuck!

Comment: I can write you an answer to your homework, but it will have a class, and a generic Sort function that takes two type parameters and a delegate as one of the function's parameters.  But, you couldn't hand that in.

Comment: I often see beginners try to create separate variables and arrays then mess up trying to keep them all synchronized. Don't do that; create a class. It really makes things easier.

Comment: Because it is for school and they do not have class

Comment: Look at your code that manipulates `arr1` (inside `if (arr1[j] < arr1[i])`). Change it to, just afterwards, do the **exact same changes** to `name`.

Comment: Another way of attacking the problem - don't sort after the fact. Use `BinarySearch` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.binarysearch?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Array_BinarySearch_System_Array_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Object_) at insertion time to work out where to insert it.

Comment: I want to do this in C #:
[link](https://www.the-art-of-web.com/php/sortarray/)

Comment: `it is for school and they do not have class` Are you not permitted, even encouraged to go forth and Learn on your own.  A Class is The Right Way to do this.

Comment: There's a reason everyone says "use a class" - it's the right way to do this.  If you look at the classic book "The C Programming Language" (remember, C is not an object-oriented language), there's only 10 pages between them sorting a collection of integer to them sorting a collection of "objects" (`struct`s).  In their example, they pass the collection and what would be a comparison delegate in C# to a sort function.  Trying to keep two arrays synchronized as you sort them is a bug farm.

Answer (score 0):

if you can use list type, you can try this code:

```
        List<dynamic> lst= new List<dynamic>();
        int n;


        Console.Write ( "\n\nSort elements of array in ascending order :\n" );
        Console.Write ( "----------------------------------------------\n" );

        Console.Write ( "Input the size of array : " );
        n = Convert.ToInt32 ( Console.ReadLine ( ) );

        Console.Write ( "Input {0} elements in the array :\n", n );
        for (var  i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        {
            Console.WriteLine ( "Enter name {0}", i );
            var name = Console.ReadLine ( );
            Console.Write ( "element - {0} : ", i );
            var elem = Convert.ToInt32 ( Console.ReadLine ( ) );
            lst.Add ( new { name = name, elem = elem } );
        }
        Console.Write ( "\nElements of array in sorted ascending order:\n" );

        lst.OrderBy ( t => t.elem ).ToList ( ).ForEach ( y => {
            Console.Write ( "{0}, {1}  ", y.elem, y.name );
        } );
        Console.Write ( "\n\n" );
        Console.ReadLine ( );
```

Comment: It works. But the input names are not matched with the ordered number

Comment: You can create a class, then replace dynamic with your class and on method add a new object type as your class